# How to show/hide my UILabel ? - UIButton does not work?

Tags: swift, button, label, edit, show-hide

I have a HUGE problem. 
What I wish for: 
I wish for a label which is hidden and uneditable when the view loads or when pressing a button besides the button with the tag "15", and by pressing the button with the tag "15" is the only way for the label to show up and be editable.

my problem:
my problem is that when the view did load, it is not hidden at all and when I press the other buttons it doesn't hide either.
I have tried to set the "label.hidden = true" 
inside the "weak var label : UILabel! {...}" (where I define the label) but when I then press the button with the tag "15" it doesn't show up.

btw don't worry about the other button tags, they are all included in the 
"buttonAclicked" function, i have not included them because i thought it would take to much space

```
 import Foundation
import UIKit






    class TriangleViewController : UIViewController {


        @IBOutlet weak var Open: UIBarButtonItem!




        @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!




        var Anumber = ""
        var Bnumber = ""
        var Cnumber = ""
        var Ynumber = ""
        var Xnumber = ""
        var znumber = ""




        @IBOutlet var btnNine: UIButton!





        @IBOutlet var btn : UIButton!
        @IBOutlet var btnOne : UIButton!




        @IBOutlet var btnThreeclicked : UIButton!





        var tags = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        var tagStrings = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "."]



        var btnArray = [UIButton]()
        var i = 0
        var activeInput = 0




        @IBOutlet var buttona : UIButton!

        @IBOutlet var buttonclicked : UIButton!




       // override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {


        //MARK: LABEL over tastatur

        weak var label : UILabel! {
            var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0 * view.bounds.width, 0.2 * view.bounds.height, 1 * view.bounds.width, 0.06 * view.bounds.height))
          //  label.center = CGPointMake(0.5 * view.bounds.width, 0.57 * view.bounds.height)
            label.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
            label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(28)
            label.text = "0"
            label.tag = 20

            self.view.addSubview(label)



            return label
        }
    // }
        weak var labelB : UILabel! {
            var labelB = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0 * view.bounds.width, 0.58 * view.bounds.height, 1.0 * view.bounds.width, 0.06 * view.bounds.height))
            labelB.center = CGPointMake(0.5 * view.bounds.width, 0.57 * view.bounds.height)
            labelB.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            labelB.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
            labelB.font = labelB.font.fontWithSize(28)
            labelB.text = "0"
            labelB.tag = 21
            self.view.addSubview(labelB)

            return labelB
        }

        weak var labelC : UILabel! {
            var labelC = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0 * view.bounds.width, 0.58 * view.bounds.height, 1 * view.bounds.width, 0.06 * view.bounds.height))
            labelC.center = CGPointMake(0.5 * view.bounds.width, 0.57 * view.bounds.height)
            labelC.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            labelC.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
            labelC.font = labelC.font.fontWithSize(28)
            labelC.text = "0"
            labelC.tag = 22
            self.view.addSubview(labelC)

            return labelC
        }

        weak var labelY : UILabel! {
            var labelY = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0 * view.bounds.width, 0.58 * view.bounds.height, 1 * view.bounds.width, 0.06 * view.bounds.height))
            labelY.center = CGPointMake(0.5 * view.bounds.width, 0.57 * view.bounds.height)
            labelY.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            labelY.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
            labelY.font = labelY.font.fontWithSize(28)
            labelY.text = "0"
            labelY.tag = 23
            self.view.addSubview(labelY)

            return labelY
        }

        weak var labelX : UILabel! {
            var labelX = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0 * view.bounds.width, 0.58 * view.bounds.height, 1 * view.bounds.width, 0.06 * view.bounds.height))
            labelX.center = CGPointMake(0.5 * view.bounds.width, 0.57 * view.bounds.height)
            labelX.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            labelX.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
            labelX.font = labelX.font.fontWithSize(28)
            labelX.text = "0"
            labelX.tag = 24
            self.view.addSubview(labelX)

            return labelX
        }





        override func viewDidLoad() {
                  Open.target = self.revealViewController()
                  Open.action = Selector("revealToggle:")










            display.hidden = true




            label.hidden = true
            labelB.hidden = true
            labelC.hidden = true
            labelX.hidden = true
            labelY.hidden = true

            //MARK: TASTATUR KNAPPER
            let btn = UIButton()
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(0.04 * view.bounds.width, 0.91 * view.bounds.height, 0.44 * view.bounds.width, 0.07 * view.bounds.height)  //set frame
            btn.setTitle("0", forState: .Normal)  //set button title
            btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal) //set button title color
            btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor() //set button background color
            btn.tag = 0 // set button tag
            btn.addTarget(self, action: "btnclicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside) //add button action
            self.view.addSubview(btn) //add button in view
            btnArray.append(btn)


            let btnDot = UIButton()
            btnDot.frame = CGRectMake(0.52 * view.bounds.width, 0.91 * view.bounds.height, 0.2 * view.bounds.width, 0.07 * view.bounds.height)  //set frame
            btnDot.setTitle(".", forState: .Normal)  //set button title
            btnDot.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal) //set button title color
            btnDot.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor() //set button background color
            btnDot.tag = 10 // set button tag
            btnDot.addTarget(self, action: "btnclicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside) //add button action
            self.view.addSubview(btnDot) //add button in view


            let btnOk = UIButton()
            btnOk.frame = CGRectMake(0.76 * view.bounds.width, 0.73 * view.bounds.height, 0.2 * view.bounds.width, 0.25 * view.bounds.height)  //set frame
            btnOk.setTitle("OK", forState: .Normal)  //set button title
            btnOk.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal) //set button title color
            btnOk.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor() //set button background color
            btnOk.tag = 11 // set button tag
            btnOk.addTarget(self, action: "btnclicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside) //add button action
            self.view.addSubview(btnOk) //add button in view

            let btnOne = UIButton()
            btnOne.frame = CGRectMake(0.04 * view.bounds.width, 0.82 * view.bounds.height, 0.2 * view.bounds.width, 0.07 * view.bounds.height)  //set frame
            btnOne.setTitle("1", forState: .Normal)  //set button title
            btnOne.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal) //set button title color
            btnOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor() //set button background color
            btnOne.tag = 1 // set button tag
            btnOne.addTarget(self, action: "btnclicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside) //add button action
            self.view.addSubview(btnOne) //add button in view
            btnArray.append(btnOne)


            let btnTwo = UIButton()
            btnTwo.frame = CGRectMake(0.28 * view.bounds.width, 0.82 * view.bounds.height, 0.2 * view.bounds.width, 0.07 * view.bounds.height)  //set frame
            btnTwo.setTitle("2", forState: .Normal)  //set button title
            btnTwo.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal) //set button title color
            btnTwo.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor() //set button background color
            btnTwo.tag = 2 // set button tag
            btnTwo.addTarget(self, action: "btnclicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside) //add button action
            self.view.addSubview(btnTwo) //add button in view

            let btnThree = UIButton()
            btnThree.frame = CGRectMake(0.52 * view.bounds.width, 0.82 * view.bounds.height, 0.2 * view.bounds.width, 0.07 * view.bounds.height)  //set frame
            btnThree.setTitle("3", forState: .Normal)  //set button title
            btnThree.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal) //set button title color
            btnThree.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor() //set button background color
            btnThree.tag = 3 // set button tag
            btnThree.addTarget(self, action: "btnclicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside) //add button action
            self.view.addSubview(btnThree) //add button in view

         //   btnThreeclicked.userInteractionEnabled = false





            let btnFour = UIButton()
            btnFour.frame = CGRectMake(0.04 * view.bounds.width, 0.73 * view.bounds.height, 0.2 * view.bounds.width, 0.07 * view.bounds.height)  //set frame
            btnFour.setTitle("4", forState: .Normal)  //set button title
            btnFour.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal) //set button title color
            btnFour.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor() //set button background color
            btnFour.tag = 4 // set button tag
            btnFour.addTarget(self, action: "btnclicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside) //add button action
            self.view.addSubview(btnFour) //add button in view


            let btnFive = UIButton()
            btnFive.frame = CGRectMake(0.28 * view.bounds.width, 0.73 * view.bounds.height, 0.2 * view.bounds.width, 0.07 * view.bounds.height)  //set frame
            btnFive.setTitle("5", forState: .Normal)  //set button title
            btnFive.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal) //set button title color
            btnFive.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor() //set button background color
            btnFive.tag = 5 // set button tag
            btnFive.addTarget(self, action: "btnclicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside) //add button action
            self.view.addSubview(btnFive) //add button in view

            let btnSix = UIButton()
            btnSix.frame = CGRectMake(0.52 * view.bounds.width, 0.73 * view.bounds.height, 0.2 * view.bounds.width, 0.07 * view.bounds.height)  //set frame
            btnSix.setTitle("6", forState: .Normal)  //set button title
            btnSix.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal) //set button title color
            btnSix.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor() //set button background color
            btnSix.tag = 6 // set button tag
            btnSix.addTarget(self, action: "btnclicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside) //add button action
            self.view.addSubview(btnSix) //add button in view

            let btnSeven = UIButton()
            btnSeven.frame = CGRectMake(0.04 * view.bounds.width, 0.64 * view.bounds.height, 0.2 * view.bounds.width, 0.07 * view.bounds.height)  //set frame
            btnSeven.setTitle("7", forState: .Normal)  //set button title
            btnSeven.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal) //set button title color
            btnSeven.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor() //set button background color
            btnSeven.tag = 7 // set button tag
            btnSeven.addTarget(self, action: "btnclicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside) //add button action
            self.view.addSubview(btnSeven) //add button in view

            let btnEight = UIButton()
            btnEight.frame = CGRectMake(0.28 * view.bounds.width, 0.64 * view.bounds.height, 0.2 * view.bounds.width, 0.07 * view.bounds.height)  //set frame
            btnEight.setTitle("8", forState: .Normal)  //set button title
            btnEight.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal) //set button title color
            btnEight.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor() //set button background color
            btnEight.tag = 8 // set button tag
            btnEight.addTarget(self, action: "btnclicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside) //add button action
            self.view.addSubview(btnEight) //add button in view

            let btnNine = UIButton()
            btnNine.frame = CGRectMake(0.52 * view.bounds.width, 0.64 * view.bounds.height, 0.2 * view.bounds.width, 0.07 * view.bounds.height)  //set frame
            btnNine.setTitle("9", forState: .Normal)  //set button title
            btnNine.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal) //set button title color
            btnNine.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor() //set button background color
            btnNine.tag = 9 // set button tag
            btnNine.addTarget(self, action: "btnclicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside) //add button action
            self.view.addSubview(btnNine) //add button in view


            let btnClear = UIButton()
            btnClear.frame = CGRectMake(0.76 * view.bounds.width, 0.64 * view.bounds.height, 0.2 * view.bounds.width, 0.07 * view.bounds.height)  //set frame
            btnClear.setTitle("C", forState: .Normal)  //set button title
            btnClear.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal) //set button title color
            btnClear.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor() //set button background color
            btnClear.tag = 99 // set button tag
            btnClear.addTarget(self, action: "btnclicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside) //add button action
            self.view.addSubview(btnClear) //add button in view







            //MARK: Knapper paa vinkler og siderne



            let buttona = UIButton()
            buttona.frame = CGRectMake(0.772 * view.bounds.width, 0.32 * view.bounds.height, 22, 22)
            buttona.layer.cornerRadius = 0.04 * view.bounds.width
            buttona.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            buttona.setImage(UIImage(named:"A.png"), forState: .Normal)
            buttona.tag = 15
            buttona.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAclicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            self.view.addSubview(buttona)


            let buttonb = UIButton()
            buttonb.frame = CGRectMake(0.47 * view.bounds.width, 0.463 * view.bounds.height, 22, 22)
            buttonb.layer.cornerRadius = 0.04 * view.bounds.width
            buttonb.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            buttonb.setImage(UIImage(named:"B.png"), forState: .Normal)
            buttonb.tag = 16
            buttonb.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAclicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            view.addSubview(buttonb)


            let buttonc = UIButton()
            buttonc.frame = CGRectMake(0.47 * view.bounds.width, 0.32 * view.bounds.height, 22, 22)
            buttonc.layer.cornerRadius = 0.04 * view.bounds.width
            buttonc.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            buttonc.setImage(UIImage(named:"C.png"), forState: .Normal)
            buttonc.tag = 17
            buttonc.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAclicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            view.addSubview(buttonc)

            let buttony = UIButton()
            buttony.frame = CGRectMake(0.772 * view.bounds.width, 0.17 * view.bounds.height, 22, 22)
            buttony.layer.cornerRadius = 0.04 * view.bounds.width
            buttony.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            buttony.setImage(UIImage(named:"Y.png"), forState: .Normal)
            buttony.tag = 18
            buttony.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAclicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            view.addSubview(buttony)

            let buttonx = UIButton()
            buttonx.frame = CGRectMake(0.19 * view.bounds.width, 0.463 * view.bounds.height, 22, 22)
            buttonx.layer.cornerRadius = 0.04 * view.bounds.width
            buttonx.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            buttonx.setImage(UIImage(named:"X.png"), forState: .Normal)
            buttonx.tag = 19
            buttonx.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAclicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            view.addSubview(buttonx)

            let buttonz = UIButton()
            buttonz.frame = CGRectMake(0.772 * view.bounds.width, 0.463 * view.bounds.height, 22, 22)
            buttonz.layer.cornerRadius = 0.04 * view.bounds.width
            buttonz.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            buttonz.setImage(UIImage(named:"Z.png"), forState: .Normal)
            buttonz.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAclicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            view.addSubview(buttonz)











            print("\(btnThreeclicked)")



              self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }




        func btnclicked(sender: UIButton) {


               // sender.currentTitle!






                   switch activeInput {
                   case 1 :
                    if sender.currentTitle == "OK" {
                           print("hey")
                    } else {
                        Anumber += sender.currentTitle!
                        label.text = Anumber
                        print("text: A \(Anumber) \(Bnumber) \(Cnumber) \(Ynumber) \(Xnumber)")
                        activeInput = 1
                    }
                        break

                   case 2 :
                        Bnumber += sender.currentTitle!
                        labelB.text = Bnumber
                        print("text: B \(Anumber) \(Bnumber) \(Cnumber) \(Ynumber) \(Xnumber)")
                        activeInput = 2
                        break
                    case 3 :
                        Cnumber += sender.currentTitle!
                        labelC.text = Cnumber
                        print("text: C \(Anumber) \(Bnumber) \(Cnumber) \(Ynumber) \(Xnumber)")
                        activeInput = 3
                        break
                   case 4 :
                        Ynumber += sender.currentTitle!
                        labelY.text = Ynumber
                        print("text: Y \(Anumber) \(Bnumber) \(Cnumber) \(Ynumber) \(Xnumber)")
                        activeInput = 4
                        break
                   case 5 :
                        Xnumber += sender.currentTitle!
                        labelX.text = Xnumber
                        print("text: X \(Anumber) \(Bnumber) \(Cnumber) \(Ynumber) \(Xnumber)")
                        activeInput = 5
                        break
                    default :
                        print("wrong")
                    activeInput = 0
                    }


     }



         func buttonAclicked(sender: UIButton) {


            switch sender.tag {
            case 11 :
                print("det virker squ")
                self.label.hidden = true
                labelB.hidden = true
                labelC.hidden = true
                labelY.hidden = true
                labelX.hidden = true
                break


                //MARK: KNAPPERNE P{ TREKANTERNE CASES
            case 15 :
                print("button A was pressed")
                self.label.hidden = false
                labelB.hidden = true
                labelC.hidden = true
                labelY.hidden = true
                labelX.hidden = true

                label.setNeedsDisplay()
                activeInput = 1
                break
            case 16 :
                 print("button B was pressed")
                self.label.hidden = true

                labelC.hidden = true
                labelY.hidden = true
                labelX.hidden = true
                labelB.hidden = false
                labelB.setNeedsDisplay()
                activeInput = 2
                break
            case 17 :
                 print("button C was pressed")
                self.labelB.hidden = true
                label.hidden = true
                labelY.hidden = true
                labelX.hidden = true
                labelC.hidden = false
                labelC.setNeedsDisplay()
                activeInput = 3
                break
            case 18 :
                print("button Y was pressed")
                label.hidden = true
                labelC.hidden = true
                labelY.hidden = false
                labelX.hidden = true
                labelB.hidden = true
                labelY.setNeedsDisplay()
                activeInput = 4
                break
            case 19 :
                print("button X was pressed")
                label.hidden = true
                labelC.hidden = true
                labelY.hidden = true
                labelX.hidden = false
                labelB.hidden = true
                labelX.setNeedsDisplay()
                activeInput = 5
                break

            default :

                print("wrong button")
                 activeInput = 0

            }





        }











    }
```

Comment: Please don't forget to mark an answer as the correct one (if it helped you/ fixed your issue). I see that you haven't accepted any answer for any of your questions. As you are fairly new here, here's how you do it: click on the checkmark next to an answer. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried : `self.label.hidden = true` ?

Furthermore, why not use an IBOutlet ? It makes EVERYTHING much easier.

Please tell us if this fixed your issue.

**EDIT:** Hmmm. This is how I would correct your code (I only included the places where I modified it):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TriangleViewController : UIViewController {

var label : UILabel!

// override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {


//MARK: LABEL over tastatur

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

        self.label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0 * view.bounds.width, 0.2 * view.bounds.height, 1 * view.bounds.width, 0.06 * view.bounds.height))
        self.label.center = CGPointMake(0.5 * view.bounds.width, 0.57 * view.bounds.height)
        self.label.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
        self.label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(28)
        self.label.text = "0"
        self.label.tag = 20

        self.view.addSubview(label)
        self.label.hidden = true
}

func buttonAclicked(sender: UIButton) {


    switch sender.tag {
    case 11 :
        print("det virker squ")
        self.label.hidden = true

        break


    //MARK: KNAPPERNE P{ TREKANTERNE CASES
    case 15 :
        print("button A was pressed")
        self.label.hidden = false

        label.setNeedsDisplay()

        break
    case 16 :
        print("button B was pressed")
        self.label.hidden = true

        break
    case 17 :
        print("button C was pressed")
        self.label.hidden = true

        break
    case 18 :
        print("button Y was pressed")
        label.hidden = true

        break
    case 19 :
        print("button X was pressed")
        label.hidden = true

        break

    default :
        print("wrong button")
    }
}
}
```

**SOLUTION :**

1) Put `self.label` where I put it.

2) Make good use of `ViewDidAppear()`.

3) Don't make your `label` a `weak` var ! In this case, nil was found because the label wasn't kept long enough in memory.

Comment: This answer should be marked as correct. I just tested the code and putting self.label.hidden = true in viewDidLoad will work. And Ghulam Ali is correct by saying that your label's position is wrong due to view not yet being initialized. Setting the frame/positon in viewDidLoad will also work.

Comment: I have tried it now and the first part works except for when I'm pressing a button  (which is not tag "15") that is supposed to hide the label again but nothing happens at all :/ i have tried to write self.label.hidden = false in my switch statement but it still doesn't work

Comment: @A.stein Please update your code so I can see where you have tried to put `self.label.hidden` so far ;)

Comment: @A.stein please replace every `label` by `self.label` and tell us how it went :D

Comment: @Coder1000 nothing really happened :/ but i must say I'm grateful for you help :)

Comment: @A.stein You didn't put it for case 15.  Also, did you move your layout code to `viewWillAppear` ? as suggested by Ghulam Ali ?

Comment: @Coder1000 It doesn't seem like it works by putting the viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad. I have tried to debug it and it says that the "self.label.hidden = true is false and i have no idea how to fix it :/

Comment: @A.stein I edited my answer. Please kindly try the code :)

Comment: @Coder1000 as much I hate to still have problems and take your time :/ the  TriangleViewConrtoller has no member of label when i put the "self.label.hidden = true" inside the ViewDidLoad, and when i delete "self." the "label" is an unsolved identifier :/ I personally think it has something to do with the "self.label.hidden = true" in the "buttonAclicked" function but i have almost no ideas

Comment: @Coder1000 well that is the code i had written to begin with and it still doesn't hide the label when i press a button (except button with tag "15") :/ and the "label.setNeedsDisplay()" doesn't solve anything :'(

Comment: @A.stein I am not letting you down. I will be back tomorrow to help. In the meantime, please post ALL your code in your question.

Comment: @Coder1000 thank you so much! Okay, i will put in ALL my codes :)

Comment: @Coder1000 OMG OMG OMG OMG OMG OMG OMG OMG IT FREAKING WORKED!!!!!  THANK YOU SO MUCH !!!!!!! YOU DONT KNOW HOW HAPPY I AM, I DONT KNOW HOW TO THANK YOU ENOUGH!!!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you are using view.bounds.width and view.bounds.height for the Label size but the view itself is not yet initialized for display, so at this point both are zero.
Move your Label code to viewWillAppear and it will work.

```
class TriangleViewController : UIViewController {
    var label: UILabel? = nil;

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0 * view.bounds.width, 0.2 * view.bounds.height, 1 * view.bounds.width, 0.06 * view.bounds.height))
        //  label.center = CGPointMake(0.5 * view.bounds.width, 0.57 * view.bounds.height)
        label!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        label!.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
        label!.font = label!.font.fontWithSize(28)
        label!.text = "0"
        label!.tag = 20

        self.view.addSubview(label!)
    }
}
```

As I have made this an option variable: UILabel?, you need to unwrap it to use. Like:

`label! or by 
if let label = label { ... }`